# sharepoint 2010 : Download Data as Excel reports

Tags: excel, reports

We are working on a share point 2010 application where there is a requirements of complex reporting.

As per requirement there will be a Link List which will have couple of links. On clicking these link user can download  reports in excel format. These Excel reports contains data from one of the List with conditional formatting. e.g. color code all the records which have order date > today.

I am not very sure if this can be achieved using any OOB functionality. if it is there. Please let me know also i will request you to help me with alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an Excel file, link it to a SharePoint List, apply your custom formatting, then have it available in a document library, the link to which is placed in your Links List.

To create the Excel link, you might ahve to first open your List in SharePoint, from the List tab in the Ribbon, click Export to Excel

All out of the box, SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Just tested this solution out in my SPS2010 VM, works well (Got a list, Item Ribbon Tab, Export to Excel). You will have to set the Data Connection to refresh data when reloading. In Excel, in the Data Tab, click Connections in the Connections Section, click Properties when owssrv[1] is selected, and check "Refresh Data when opening the file".

Comment: I did try it but could not get any formatting. how do I make sure My macro enable Excel template (store in doc library) is opened when i am exporting the list. i think I was not able to linking correctly. Please details the steps if possible..